# Can I connect with this driver

Tags: sql-server, odbc

One of my laptops still has Windows XP and SQL Server ODBC driver version 2008.85.1132.00.

Unfortunately this laptop has a software that I can't put on the machine where I have SQL Server 2012 and it looks like there is no ODBC driver for WinXP anymore for Server 2012.

So, I'm wondering if I can get a connection with that driver to my Server. Or the driver will be incompatible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Windows ship with a legacy SQL Server ODBC driver named `"SQL Server"`.  That ODBC driver may be used to connect to SQL Server 2012 as well as older and newer versions of SQL Server.  However, it may nto fully support the newer SQL Server data types.

According to the [SQL Server Native Client Support Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280356.aspx), the most recent Microsoft-supplied ODBC driver supported under Windows XP SP2 is the SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client.