# Connecting to MS SQL Server 2012 from WinXP

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970209/can-i-connect-with-this-driver), I can connect to the MS SQL Server 2012 from Windows XP using "Generic ODBC MS SQL" driver.

So, I tried to do just that. Both machines are connected to the Windows Workgroup.

First just to make sure, I tried to ping the machine where server is located by IP. The ping was successful.

Next I went to the ODBC Manager in Windows XP and tried to configure a new connection. I used an IP address of the machine where SQL Server is installed in the "Server:" field. And then I used "With Windows NT authentication" selection. However, trying to establish a connection - it is failed.

The failure reported was as follows:

```
Connection failed!
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 1326
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen(Connect())
Connection failed!
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied
```

Just to prove there is no Firewall, I set my ZoneAlarm FW on the Server host for "Trustged Zone Security" to "None" and tried again. Got the same results.

The SQL Server is using trusted connection, meaning that I can connect with the user id/password from the computer. This laptop is using Windows 8.1. The Windows XP laptop using the same user id to login but different password. Could this be an issue?

What else I can try to get a connection? I need to test my application that it will work.

Thank you.

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled in the Server? See `Sql Server Configuration Manager` -> `Client Protocols`

Comment: @erg, Looking at the Client Protocols for both SQL Native Client 11.0 32-bit and 64-bit - they are both enabled. However, SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS/MSSQLSERVER TCP/IP is disabled for both and I can't turn it on. The combo box shows up empty/disabled. Does this mean I need to install something?

Comment: Sorry, I have no ideas. I tried to reproduce it here - the entries to enable / disable TCP/IP are never disabled here. I did not install anything special, I just run the "normal" SQL Server setup.

Comment: @erg, Maybe it has something to do with different credentials? The server is set up to give access by machine login and credentials on XP are different than on 8.

Comment: @erg, Or maybe its not possible with SQL Server Express 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Could be the connection with the server, or user permission so...

in one hand if you use Windows Authentication to remote access, you have 2 options, in one option you must to have a Domain and all users must be a domain users, and you get access to a some users/group of this domain in the sqlserver.

Other Option is create a sqlserver user account, and use it to log in.

In your case, the server doesn't know the user from remote pc who is trying to login in.

on the other hand, you can check the server connection, you can create a empty file in your desktop an save it with .udl extension. Now open it, and you can create your connection and test it.

When you finish, if you open the `.udl` file with notepad you can see the string connection.

here you have a tutorial to create and test connections with .udl files: [link .udl](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/)

how to create sqlserver login: [sqlserver login](https://www.supremainc.com/es/node/618)

and here you have how to add domain user to sqlserver login: [sqlserver login for a domain account](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15737/how-to-create-sql-server-login-for-a-domain-account)

hope this help!